# Port Wince 7 Xaml Based application to win32 platform

Tags: c++, xaml, winapi, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a WEC7 Xaml based application, which i tried to port it to Win32 platform( for Windows 7).
During the porting, i am getting below error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xamlruntime.h': No such file or directory.
```

How to overcome this issue. Can be port wince Xaml based application to win32 platform?

Can be create a Xaml based desktop application?

Any input will be appreciable.